# Linq date and datetime comparer

Tags: linq, datetime, date, linq-to-entities

I need to get the query of the day, the problem is that I'm getting an error when I try to compare the value that comes from the DB (which is a `DateTime`), against the `DateTime.Today.Date` value.

What I'm trying to achieve is to get the registers of the day.

```
List<Client> _cliente = from c in db.Cliente
                        join v in db.Vendedor
                        on c.IDVendedor equals v.IDVendedor
                        where v.Fecha.Date.Equals(DateTime.Today.Date)
```

This is what I'm getting: 'The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you can do something like this:

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
var tomorrow = today.AddDays(1);

List<Client> _cliente = from c in db.Cliente
                    join v in db.Vendedor
                    on c.IDVendedor equals v.IDVendedor
                    where v.Fecha >= today && v.Fecha < tomorrow
```

Comment: This is based on the fact that DateTime.Today will return the date with the time set to 00:00:00.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the C# standard library -- There is a time interval type (subtract one time from another, then get the absolute value of the number of days, like so:

```
List<Client> _cliente = from c in db.Cliente
                    join v in db.Vendedor
                    on c.IDVendedor equals v.IDVendedor
                    where Math.Abs((v.Fecha.Date - DateTime.Today).Days) <= 1
```

Comment: I believe it should be `DateTime.Today` as above.